# Show one element of a mongoDB collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, es6-promise

I have mongodb collection from where I need to extract highschool and college to their respective route. 
My collection looks like this

{
    "_id" : "1f24ef0c-6f9c-478a-adc9-7c55d7708930",
    "highSchool" : "Modern Era Convent",
    "college" : "Stevens Institute of Technology"
}

My routes looks like this :-

```
const data = require("../data");
const educationData = data.education;

    router.get("/highschool", (req, res) => {
        educationData.getHighSchool().then((education) => {
            res.json(education);
        }, () => {
            // Not found!
            res.sendStatus(404);
        });
    });

    router.get("/", (req, res) => {
        educationData.getAllEducation().then((EducationList) => {
            res.json(EducationList);
        }, () => {
            // Something went wrong with the server!
            res.sendStatus(500);
        });
    });
```

My "/" routes returns id, college and highschool. But in the  "/highschool" I want to extract only the name of the highschool present in the collection. How can I achieve that.Currently I am using the following function to return the data.

```
    const education = mongoCollections.education;// added for reference

    return education().then((educationCollection) => {
            return educationCollection.find({}).toArray();
        });
    },

    getHighSchool(){
        return education().then((educationCollection)=> {
            return educationCollection.highSchool;
        });
    }
```

"getAllEducation" function is returning everything but "getHighSchool" is not returning anything.

Comment: Who is your view? It's missing the `getAllEducation` in your code, right?

Answer (score 0):

Missing the query in the `getHighScholl` method

```
getHighSchool(){
    return education().then((educationCollection)=> {
        return educationCollection.findOne({}).highSchool;
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried using this, but  my webpage is  not showing anything. Neither the output nor the "internal server" or "not found" error. @MarceloRisse

Comment: @ArjunDass could you post what is shown if you print the server's response to the browser's console?